# Getting Arcsin and Arccos value as constants and fractions

Tags: c#, math

Is it possible to get the value of Asin and Acos as constant values for ex.

Math.Asin(-1) is PI/2 but I get the value 1,57079 how can I transform the 1,57079 automatically to PI/2 as a string?

Comment: Multiply the return value by 180/Math.PI to convert from radians to degrees.

Comment: If you divide 1.57079 by Pi, you'll get value about 1/2. But what are you going to do with this result?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what type or format you want to *output*. Is it something like `ᴨ⁄₂`? A string? Try to clarify your requirements and the data type involved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to multiply the return value by `180/Math.PI` to convert from radians to degrees.

```
var angle = Math.Asin(-1) * 180 / Math.PI; // it sets angle to -90 that is equivalent to PI/2
```

Comment: I don't want to convert to degrees i want the values as fractions combined with PI 1,5707 is half of a pi

Comment: Math.Asin(-1)  will return -1.57079......there is no datatype bin c# to present value exactly like PI. Its double value. If you want you can create a mapping like 90 to string PI